# Set fallback bitmap image when vector drawables aren't supported

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developping an app that will run on devices with API 15 or higher. Vector drawables have only been available since API 21 however. I would love to make my app use vector drawables when possible, but if it isn't, fall back to the PNG drawables.

How do I set this up in Android Studio? Is this even possible?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Can you please elaborate? There doesn't seem to be any Support Library support for vector drawables.

Comment: Hmmm.. no, you are right... Another thing **they forgot to include** (still waiting for PreferenceFragments!!)... Then, I'd go for REAL `SVG` files (VectorDrawables are just a **subset**), through the use of a `free library`. There are several ones to choose from. My favourites: `android-svg` and `svg-android`.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein That seems a bit tedious for something that should be so straight forward. I'll just use bitmaps for now, as there doesn't seem to be a significant drawback. I'm still hoping some Android guru knows of a way though.

Comment: You can easily transform your VectorDrawables into SVG files (since they are a **superset**). And one of the libraries I tested was only 31KB in size... and very easy to use. Well documented, with working example...

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Thing is, it requires Java code. My Java code is a mess as-is, I would like to be able to do this within 5 lines of java, if absolutely needed. Rewriting the design library just so it uses svgs is a bit over the top.

Comment: I see. Ok... But try to keep your code nice and clean. This is a free advice! ;)